# how can I uninstall scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have installed scrapy0.14 through easy_install scrapy, but now I find that scrapy0.24.5 is more useful, I hope to unstall the old scrapy and install new scrapy by pip, how can I uninstall the old one?

Answer (score 2):

Look in /usr/local/bin/python2.6/dist-packages or /usr/local/bin/python2.6/site-packages and remove any scrapy directories (and files) you find there. Next time, use "pip install" instead of easy_install, so you can use "pip uninstall" to uninstall.